# difference between List and Publication List

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

What is the difference between List and Publication List in Salesforce Marketing cloud??

List:
https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/lists/

publication list:
https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/publication_lists/

Comment: The 2 links provided above are broken, can you please update the links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send to Lists directly.  Publication Lists are only associated with sends and can't be sent to directly.  Publication Lists are normally used for associating a Publication (campaign, segment, etc.) with a send to a Data Extension (DE).

SFMC maintains subscriber status for both.  So if you send to a DE, with an associated Publication List and the subscriber unsubscribes they'd only be unsubscribed from the Publication List (assuming they don't check the global opt-out checkbox).

Both show on the stock Preference/Subscription Center pages if they're marked as public.

"All Subscribers" is the master List.

Both are considered Lists when you're dealing with the API or the System Data Views.